# html twig file can't find the path to my css file in Symfony app

Tags: html, css, symfony, twig

I started a new project in symfony.  I'm very new to it, but I followed all the instructions from symfony's documentation for the installation:

```js
/* assets/styles/app.css */
body {
    background-color: rgb(177, 44, 44);
}
 h1{
     color: red;
 }

 h2{
     color:purple;
     border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```css
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    <h1> Bienvenue à tous </h1>
    <h2> Bienvenue 2 </h2>

{% endblock %}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {# Run `composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle`
           and uncomment the following Encore helpers to start using Symfony UX #}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\styles\app.css" type="text/css">
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {#{{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}#}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block javascripts %}
            {#{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}#}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here][1] set up. I downloaded webpack-encore-bundle package with yarn package manager. I think that my () is well placed, but my html file can't find the path to my css.

here are my files
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RA9FJ.png

my network browser console tell me this "net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Does the `public` folder contain an `assets` folder, or a symlink to the given one?

Comment: My problem is solved. I didn't complete the part of building the asset. I had nothing in my public folder. So I have run the "yarn encore dev" command and now i got the build folder inside public. I changed the css link for (<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/app.css">) and now it's working. thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### With Webpack Encore

You should not write your `<link>`-tag yourself and instead use the commented `encore_entry_link_tags` instead. The `encore_entry_link_tags` will make sure it points to the file generated by Webpack Encore (after calling `yarn encore dev` for example).

When you use Webpack Encore use the `webpack.config.yaml` to point to your CSS in assets using `addEntry('app', ...file..)` (or possibly `addStyleEntry`, but addEntry should be fine). Webpack Encore takes the file under `assets/styles/app.css` and then puts it in `public/` by default `public/build`. Depending on your configuration it might be, that your file name will not stay the same during that process. The good thing is Webpack Encore usually takes care of everything for you. (If not feel free to open a question for that).

See also: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html

### When not using Webpack Encore

You should use forward slashes, e.g. `assets/styles/app.css`. If you don't use Webpack Encore then you should make sure that you have the file in `public/assets/styles/app.css` to make it accessible for your browser. You should also wrap this into another helper function called `asset`. In other words it should look something like (assuming the path is correct):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ path('assets/styles/app.css') }}" type="text/css">
```

What this will do is make sure that your path is relative to the document root (your `public/`-directory) instead of relative to the url. This is important, because otherwise your path will not have the same result depending on whether you are for example on https:/example.com vs. https://example.com/blog, because it will look for your css in different places (either `public/assets/styles/app.css` or `public/blog/assets/styles/app.css`).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't run (yarn encore dev) and i had nothing in my public folder. Now i have my build folder, i changed the css link for (<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/app.css">) and now it's working.

Comment: If you use Encore using `/build/app.css` might still not be safe depending on your webpack-configuration. For example if you run `yarn encore prod` it might add a version identifier to the file, which your example does not catch. Be sure to use the helpers or ensure your config provides the expected output also in prod.

Comment: Ok, but what do you refer to for helper function or helpers ? And i don't have the assets folder inside the public. I have the asset folder separate from public as you can see  in the screenshot on my first post. Is it normal ? Srry i'm asking a lot  but i'm a total beginner right now

Comment: The ones in `{% block stylesheets %}` and `{% block javascripts %}`. They will create the right`<link>` and `<script>` (if necessary, otherwise they are empty) tags for you. You just have to replace the `{# #}` (comment) with `{{ }}`, e.g. `{{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}`.